# What is the halacha regarding archeological digging near the Temple Mount?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, kedusha-holiness, archaeology

Follow up to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/94224/5275) that discusses the holiness of the stone that fell off the Western Wall.

What is the halachic status regarding any *kedusha* (holiness) in doing archeological excavations on the Temple Mount? When I last visited Jerusalem (too long ago - I'm overdue!) I recall seeing that to the left of the Kotel there were many deep excavations. My brother, a licensed tour guide explained that Jerusalem was built in layers. So, the top layer was built post-Temple period, but archeologist may have dug down to an area as far back as the 1st Temple period.

If any of these stones or, perhaps, if they find any remnants of 1st Temple utensils (a firepan or some other tools related to the sacrificial offerings, etc.) do these have holiness? What if there is a *safek* (doubt)? Archeologists find something but they aren't sure what it is or when it dates from? Can they dig further, or can they take a sample to a lab to determine what it is? Or do they need to err on the cautious side and assume that it **might** have *kedusha*?

Comment: They found a golden bell probably from the Kohein Gadols tunic http://www.shabes.net/bsd/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1572:paamon&catid=61:categorytorascience&Itemid=153 It was in the sewer system, probably from an attempted escape around Tisha Bav. Josephus tells of people trying to escape through the sewers and getting caught

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to know. What does holiness have to do with digging? Are you asking if you can eat dinner out of a bowl from temple times in case it belonged to Hekdesh? What sort of Kedusha were you thinking of? Please edit to clarify

Comment: it is a good and legit question - e.g. how digging on the Temple Mount is different from digging in Ashdod? Any precautions? Is everybody allowed - בעל קרי, for example? What are the different boundaries of holiness? +1

Comment: @AlBerko Here, I'm asking what can be dug. I think what you mentioned should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: Do you mean what area? what artifacts? needs more elaboration.